# How can we append unbalanced row on Pandas dataframe in the fastest way?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I am going to make pandas dataframe from unbalanced csv file

But the speed is too slow when I make it in a brute force way.

Here, I have the list of columns which can make Schema of Dataframe

And a bunch of rows in a file.

How could I make it fast?

(Should I make empty list in a different way?)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

for key in column_name:

    newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_name[key])
    with open(str(key) +'.csv') as f:
        reader1 = csv.reader(f)
        index = 0

        print key, sum(1 for row in csv.reader(open(str(key) +'.csv')))

        for row in reader1:

            if index % 10000 == 0:
                print index

            new_row = [np.nan]*len(column_name[key])            
            for i in range(len(row)):
                new_row[i] = row[i]

            newdf.loc[index] = new_row
            index = index+1

    newdf.to_csv(key+"_with_column_name"+".csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pd.DataFrame` can build a DataFrame from a list of ragged rows:

```
In [17]: pd.DataFrame([['a','b'],[1,2,3]])
Out[17]: 
   0  1    2
0  a  b  NaN
1  1  2  3.0
```

Moreover, it is faster to build the DataFrame with one call to `pd.DataFrame`
than many calls to `newdf.loc[index] = new_row` in a loop.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# column_name = {'foo':['A','B']}
for key in column_name:
    with open('{}.csv'.format(key), 'r') as f:
        reader1 = csv.reader(f)
        data = list(reader1)
        nrows = len(data)
        print('{}, {}'.format(key, nrows))
        newdf = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=column_name[key])
    # do stuff with newdf (1)
    newdf.to_csv('{}_with_column_name.csv'.format(key))
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that if your sole purpose is to create the a new CSV with
column names, then it would be quicker to simply write the column names to the
new file and then copy the contents from the old CSV into the new CSV. Building a
DataFrame would not be necessary in this case and would slow down performance.

```
for key in column_name:
    newname = '{}_with_column_name.csv'.format(key)
    with open('{}.csv'.format(key), 'r'), open(newname, 'w') as f, g:
        g.write(','.join(column_name[key])+'\n') # assuming no quotation necessary
        g.write(f.read())
```